# How to navigate to different views in a side bar in swift?

Tags: swiftui

How do I navigate to other views I have created in swiftui?
below Is some code for the side bar I tried doing myself. the issue I was having is a white screen shows up as a huge white button.

```
VStack {
         NavigationView {   
            HStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: SettingsView()) {
                    Text("Settings")
                        .font(.system(size:20))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                }
    
                NavigationLink(destination: Settings()) {
                    Text("Settings")
                    .font(.title2)
                }
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: AboutUs()) {
                  Text("About us")
                    .font(.title2)
                    
                }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Do you want to navigation within the sidebar itself or have links in the sidebar that affect the main content view of the app?

Comment: navigate within the sidebar itself to move to different views

Comment: So the main content view will stay the same but the view in the sidebar will change?

Comment: so I want to have it that the user will open the side bar from the main content view to navigate to a different view then comeback to the main content view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're within a `NavigationView`, which has very specific appearances on iOS and macOS, you wouldn't be using `NavigationLink`. Since you're making your own sidebar, that means you won't be using Navigation View/Link.

Instead, you can use a @State variable or ObservableObject with a @Published property that keeps track of what view is active. I chose the latter in this example:

```
enum ViewTypes {
    case main
    case settings
    case aboutUs
}

class SidebarNavigationManager : ObservableObject {
    @Published var viewType : ViewTypes = .main
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var navigationManager = SidebarNavigationManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            SidebarView(navigationManager: navigationManager)
            .frame(width: 100)
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
            .border(Color.green)
            
            //Main content
            VStack {
                switch navigationManager.viewType {
                case .main:
                    MainView()
                case .settings:
                    SettingsView()
                case .aboutUs:
                    AboutUsView()
                }
            }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}

struct SidebarView : View {
    @ObservedObject var navigationManager : SidebarNavigationManager
    
    var body: some View {
        //Sidebar
        VStack {
            Button(action: { navigationManager.viewType = .main }) {
                Text("Main")
            }
            Button(action: { navigationManager.viewType = .settings }) {
                Text("Settings")
            }
            Button(action: { navigationManager.viewType = .aboutUs }) {
                Text("About Us")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MainView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Main")
    }
}

struct SettingsView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Settings")
    }
}

struct AboutUsView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("About Us")
    }
}
```

Comment: I have trouble pushing the sidebar into the Home Screen when I click a button to open it from the content view.

Comment: now that you've helped me create the sidebar how do I view it on the content screen (home screen) . I want to implement the sidebar within the content view that the user will tap a button to open it from the content view.

Comment: Sorry, this is still unclear to me. I’ve shown you the sidebar and I’ve shown you how to navigate. The wording of what you’re asking is too confusing for me me to be able to figure out how to help.

Comment: right now I get an error from the above code you presented that missing argument for parameter 'navigationManager' in call in the SidebarView in the preview side of the view, when I try passing 'navigationManager in and assigning SidebarNavigationManager I still get an error

Comment: You would have to show your code. I didn’t include a preview.

Comment: struct SidebarView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SidebarView(*here*) 
    }
}

Comment: oh ok I just removed the preview

Comment: thanks for your help but right now once I applied all the code help you've given me but I have an issue. Once I open the sidebar menu from the content screen I see the other views and not actually the button itself to navigate to the other views.

Comment: The sidebar example in this answer has buttons to navigate to other views. If you're having a problem with it, you'd have to show me how you changed the code.

Comment: I realised its how I have implemented it. I have to make some few tweaks to get it the way I want it as in, I wanted it that once the user opens the sidebar it navigates to another view then closes the sidebar. the user will press a back button to return to the content view.  I don't want the side bar in all views and neither fixed in all views.

Comment: Okay. I hope you’ll consider marking this answer as correct, as it answers the original question.

Comment: I sent an email to you for some help on something.

Comment: if I don't want the coded navigation bar in each view once the user navigates to a different view using the sidebar menu how do I implement this?