# Side menu bar in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

i want to create a sidemenu bar in SwiftUI.

// Below is code for the custom bar view i want to use for the content view.

```
VStack {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation {
                            sidebarShowns.toggle()
                        }
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3")
                            .font(.headline)
                        }.padding(.leading)
                    }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    
                    Text("WeCollab")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.title)
                }
                .background(Color.purple.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top))
       }
}
```

i want the sidemenu bar view to utilise this custom bar that once the user taps the 3 horizontal lines icon the custom sidemenu bar is opened on the left side of the screen.

i want it to work like, once the opens the side menu bar by tapping the 3 horizontal lines icon user sees 3 buttons such as settings, main and about us. Once the user taps for eg, about us, the about us view is opened fully on the iPhone screen and the custom bar is hidden and the side menu is closed automatically. the user will navigate back to the original view using the back button "this back button utilises a left-chevron icon".

i don't want the custom bar on each view neither the side menu in each view.

i want to be able to do this using one SwiftUI view file for each view that will be linked to reach each view as a button within the side menu bar.

//example of some code i had but doesn't work in the way i want it to.

```
import SwiftUI

enum ViewTypesz {
    case main
    case settings
    case aboutUs
    
}

class SidebarNavigationManagerz : ObservableObject {
    @Published var viewType : ViewTypesz = .main
}


struct testView: View {
    @State private var sidebarShowns = false
    @StateObject var navigationManagers = SidebarNavigationManagerz()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            if sidebarShowns {
                SidebarView(navigationManagers: navigationManagers)
                    .frame(width: 250)
                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .border(Color.red)
                    .transition(sidebarShowns ? .move(edge: .leading) : .move(edge: .trailing) )
                        .background(customBlueColour)
                        .opacity(60.0)
                        }
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation {
                            sidebarShowns.toggle()
                        }
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3")
                            .font(.headline)
                        }.padding(.leading)
                    }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    
                    Text("WeCollab")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.title)
                }
                .background(Color.purple.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top))
                
                VStack {
                    switch navigationManagers.viewType {
                    case .main:
                        MainView()
                    case .settings:
                        SettingsViewz(navigationManagers: navigationManagers)
                    case .aboutUs:
                        AboutUsView()
                   // case .homeview:
                     //   HomeView()
                    }
                }.frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
            }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            
        }                                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)

        
    }
}

struct SidebarView : View {
    @ObservedObject var navigationManagers : SidebarNavigationManagerz
    
    var body: some View {
        //Sidebar
        VStack {
            Button(action: { navigationManagers.viewType = .main }) {
                Text("Main")
            }
            Button(action: { navigationManagers.viewType = .settings }) {
                Text("Settings")
            }
            Button(action: { navigationManagers.viewType = .aboutUs }) {
                Text("About Us")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MainView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Main")
            
    }
}

struct SettingsViewz: View {
    @ObservedObject var navigationManagers : SidebarNavigationManagerz
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Settings")
        Button("Go home") {
            navigationManagers.viewType = .settings
        }
    }
}

struct AboutUsView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("About Us")
    }
}
struct testView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        testView()
    }
}
```

here is a link to a solution i found but i couldn't mould to make it work the way i wanted it but helped.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66933468/15284614

Comment: @jnpdx perhaps you could help.

Comment: Try this library for side menu https://github.com/amirpirzad/TwitterSideMenu

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do what you want:

```
enum ViewTypesz {
    case main
    case settings
    case aboutUs
    
}

class SidebarNavigationManagerz : ObservableObject {
    @Published var viewType : ViewTypesz = .main
    @Published var sidebarShown = false
    
    func navigateToViewType(_ type: ViewTypesz) {
        viewType = type
        sidebarShown = false
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder var viewForType : some View {
        switch viewType {
        case .main:
            EmptyView()
        case .aboutUs:
            AboutUsView()
        case .settings:
            SettingsViewz()
        }
    }
    
    var bindingForNavLink : Binding<Bool> {
        .init { () -> Bool in
            return self.viewType != .main
        } set: { (newValue) in
            if !newValue { self.viewType = .main }
        }

    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var navigationManagers = SidebarNavigationManagerz()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            if navigationManagers.viewType != .main {
                NavigationLink(destination: navigationManagers.viewForType, isActive: navigationManagers.bindingForNavLink, label: { EmptyView() })
            }
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                ZStack {
                    VStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            withAnimation {
                                navigationManagers.sidebarShown.toggle()
                            }
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3")
                                .font(.headline)
                        }.padding(.leading)
                    }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    
                    Text("WeCollab")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.title)
                }
                .background(Color.purple.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top))
                
                ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                    VStack(alignment: .center) {
                        MainView()
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    
                    if navigationManagers.sidebarShown {
                        SidebarView(navigationManagers: navigationManagers)
                            .frame(width: 250)
                            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                            .border(Color.red)
                            .transition(navigationManagers.sidebarShown ? .move(edge: .leading) : .move(edge: .trailing) )
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .opacity(60.0)
                    }
                }
            }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct SidebarView : View {
    @ObservedObject var navigationManagers : SidebarNavigationManagerz
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: { navigationManagers.navigateToViewType(.aboutUs) }) {
                Text("About us")
            }
            Button(action: { navigationManagers.navigateToViewType(.settings) }) {
                Text("Settings")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MainView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Main")
        
    }
}

struct SettingsViewz: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Settings")
    }
}

struct AboutUsView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("About Us")
    }
}
```

How it works:

1. The `SidebarNavigationManagerz` maintains the state of whether the sidebar is shown and if a NavigationLink for another view is active (through the custom binding)
2. The main view has the sidebar and custom header and the `NavigationView`'s header hidden
3. Sidebar links trigger the `navigateToViewType`
4. There's a `NavigationLink` on the main page that is only active if the view type in the navigation manager is set to something other than `.main`

There's currently a transition I'm not crazy about when going back to the main view where the header isn't immediately visible, but that's detail work that you can focus on. This should get you on the right path

Comment: I was tweaking the code given and it crashed, idk why. How i set it up is to have a ui view file for each view  i want to navigate to. and a normal swift file for the sidemenu; the sidemenu file contained the view types and the class SidebarNavigationManagerz. Why i set it up so don't have all the code in one view file.

Comment: That all sounds fine. If you say "it crashed", you should say specifically what that means.

Comment: it says specifically that the preview crashed. How do i fix this?

Comment: That doesn't give me any useful information. You'd have to show me exactly the code you're using.

Comment: seems to work on my iPhone, right now the views that the sidebar are supposed to navigate to are showing the each view not the buton - how do i fix this? @jnpdx

Comment: "are showing the each view not the buton" -- I don't know what this means.

Comment: so like lets say i within the sidebar menu its supposed to be a bunch of buttons that leads to a different views eg, settings view, instead what i see when i test run the application is settings view not a button that leads to that view. is this clear enough?

Comment: The code that I gave you has buttons in the sidebar that lead to the different views. If you have changed the code to make that not the case, you'd have to show that code.

Comment: i haven't changed the code like i said i separated the view files and have a sidemenu bar view file with a side menu class and the main view with the sidebar itself with and nav bar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230964/discussion-between-jnpdx-and-rookie1z).